# Grails 5.2.0 -- cannot deploy to JBOS EAP 7.4

Tags: grails, jboss

1. grails create-app example
2. grails war
3. deploying war to JBOSS 7.4 (failed to deployed see error below)
   NOTE: tomcat -- works!
   JBOSS deployed ERROR:
   {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit."grailsJboss7Point4Test-0.1.war".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
   Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor)."}}

Comment: This is a know issue. I am currently working on it and will publish a fix early next week. Please track the progress at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/12589.

Comment: Sorry! -- Grails 5.2.2 failed deployment to JBOSS 7.4 same  caused by same error